# Read from text file, and return into arraylist in private method

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist

I have try many things, and I am so stuck in this problem.

I have to read from a text file, and throw it inside an arraylist in a private method.

And then make a new method that will print the arraylist out.

This is what I have tried so far.

I get this error:

```
fileHandling.java:11: readArray(java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>) in fileHandling cannot be applied to ()
  readArray();      
  ^
1 error
```

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class fileHandling {   
    private ArrayList<String> Person;

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        readArray();      
    }

    private ArrayList readFile() throws Exception {
        File file = new File("person.rtf");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String str = scanner.nextLine();
            Person.add(str);                     
        }
        return Person;
    }

    public void readArray(ArrayList<String> Person) {  

        for(int i =0; i < Person.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(Person.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

I think the error is when I called my method, what is going inside the brackets?

Comment: you need to initialize your ArrayList. Also use camelCase for vatiable names.

Comment: And also you're calling `readArray` as if it's a static method. Oh, and your `readFile` method is declared to return a raw type...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues (that I see).

1) You aren't instantiating an instance of your class.

2) You aren't reading the file.

3) You aren't calling `readArray` with the `List`.

4) You have no `List` instance.

5) `ArrayList<String> readFile()`

I think you want something like this,

```
private ArrayList<String> Person = new ArrayList<String>();
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
  // readArray();
  fileHandling fh = new fileHandling();
  fh.readArray(fh.readFile()); // <-- something like this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a bufferedInputStream to read your file...

variables should not be capitalized and your array should also be called persons and not Person.

Don't forget to initialize your 
    ArrayList persons = new ArrayList();

Your main method should call the read method first.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 7, it is as easy as:

```
// returns a List<String> with all lines in the file
Files.readAllLines(thePath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you won't be able to access readArray() from your main since readArray() is not static. In your current context you'd need to create an instance of fileHandling in your main and call readArray() on it.

Second, your readArray() method is declared with an ArrayList Person as a parameter, but you're calling it without the parameter in your main method.

Third, it won't help with the compilation, but rule of thumb in Java is to capitalize the first letter of a class (Should be FileHandling) and to not capitalize the first letter of a declaration (ArrayList Person should really be ArrayList person).

Comment: Could you please be a little bit more specific, what I need to do?